# Can't run .bundle file in Mac OSX

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, bundle

I was trying to open a simple .bundle file in OS X.

When I run the executable code inside the "Mac OS" folder (32 bit Unix file) this message appears in the terminal:

**-bash: /Applications/Waves/Waves Plug-Ins/PAZ.bundle/Contents/MacOS/PAZ: cannot execute binary file
logout**

The file is broken or am I doing wrong something?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is normal. Bundles are not intended to run as standalone executables, but to be loaded as plug-ins into some other program (in this case Waves). It's generally not possible to run them on their own.